# ASP.NET MVC Registration alert SQL func user existence

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, error-handling

I am working on registration in ASP.NET MVC. I am using a SQL Server function to check if user with same username/email already exists. I'm not professional at programming since maybe there could be an obvious solution which I didn't find so far.

I am trying to call alert popup message via the controller or the SQL Server function directly like "There is already a user with same Username/Email.".

I returned a bit from the SQL Server function and convert it to Boolean in controller and trying to find a way to alert a message by either using javascript with model, or maybe try to use if statements in View with value passed down via the controller.

SQL Server function code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[userExists]
     (@email VARCHAR(1024), 
      @userName VARCHAR(1024))
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
    IF ((SELECT Email FROM Users WHERE Email = @email) IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        RETURN 1
    END

    IF ((SELECT UserName FROM Users WHERE UserName = @userName) IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        RETURN 1
    END

    RETURN 0
END
```

Controller action code:

```
SqlCommand eCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT dbo.userExists(@email, @userName)", con);
eCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("email", regModel.Email);
eCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("userName", regModel.UserName);

bool exists = Convert.ToBoolean(eCmd.ExecuteScalar());

eCmd.Dispose();

if (exists != true)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Users (UserName, Email, Password) VALUES (@userName, @email, @password)", con);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("userName", regModel.UserName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("email", regModel.Email);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("password", MD5Hash(regModel.Password));

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd.Dispose();
}
else
{                                             
    return View();
}
```

Everything works so far. What I'm trying to achieve is message alert that indicates if the user already exists.

I've tried to research how to, tried what I could, used "return JavaScript("\code\");" but, didn't want to work.

Comment: **WHY** are you using `.ExecuteScalar()` for an `INSERT` operation that doesn't return any data?? For such a case, use `.ExecuteNonQuery()` instead....

Comment: Ah, I missed that part. I'll change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int result=0;
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Users (UserName, Email, Password) VALUES (@userName, @email, @password)", con);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("userName", regModel.UserName);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("email", regModel.Email);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("password", MD5Hash(regModel.Password));

result=cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd.Dispose();
```

Now based on the value you are getting,you can alert the message using jQuery. you can pass this value as `Model` or in `viewBag`. I will try with `viewbag` as

```
ViewBag.resultOfQuery=result;
return View();
```

from front end in your jQuery you can alert based `@ViewBag.resultOfQuery` as

```
<script>
 function YourFunctionName()
  {
    if('@ViewBag.resultOfQuery'=="1")
       alert("There is already a user with same Username/Email.");
    else
       alert("Inserted Successfully");
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Very well, it works! All I did was in else statement, I used ViewBag.EmailExists = 1 and included js code, tested and now it worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your `controller` method you need to use `ExecuteNonQuery` to get something in return from sql statement. And you must store your value in some variable getting from the function.

```
if (exists != true)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Users (UserName, Email, Password) VALUES (@userName, @email, @password)", con);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("userName", regModel.UserName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("email", regModel.Email);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("password", MD5Hash(regModel.Password));

    ViewBag.myval = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  // need to use ExecuteNonQuery 

    cmd.Dispose();
}
else
{                                             
    return View();
}
```

On view, to access your value

```
 @Model.myval
```

After that you may use `javascript` to post your message. As per your product structure.

Comment: That's good just the only thing is that the ViewBag.myval is assigned only if email doesn't exist so all I'm saying is that I just want to make things match the way so I know where is what. Since what I learned from this post is that I can assign a custom ViewBag variable, I can just stick with ViewBag.EmailExists = 1 or 0 which works.